# Where can I get MongoDB PHP driver for PHP 5.4 precompiled for Windows?

Tags: windows, mongodb, binary, php-mongodb, php-5.4

Where can I get mongo php driver for PHP 5.4? For windows vc9 not thread safe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<del>I've asked [@stealth35](https://twitter.com/#!/stealth35) to compile the MongoDB driver on Windows for PHP 5.4 and he posted it in less than 30 minutes.</del>

<del>You can find it here: https://github.com/stealth35/stealth35.github.com/downloads</del>

---

<del>**Update (04/26/2012):** Just realized that the official MongoDB PHP drivers have been updated and you can download them from the PHP driver [Github page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads).</del>

---

**Update (08/27/2013):** They are now available [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html). Thanks [Derick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576849/where-can-i-get-mongodb-php-driver-for-php-5-4-precompiled-for-windows/9670946?noredirect=1#comment26008792_9670946)!

Comment: Just as an update, they are now here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html